# How to create a list of lists by combining lists of strings of a column with python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, nested-lists

I have a column in my dataset consisting of lists of strings like below:

column

['tablet', 'mobile', 'man']

['people', 'house']

. . .

['people', 'computer']

['computer', 'laptop']

How can I get a list of lists with the elements of this column? I want the output like this:

[['tablet', 'mobile', 'man'],['people', 'house'],. . .,['people', 'computer'],['computer', 'laptop']]

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Please include a minimal reproducible example. Showing code building an example of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for convert strings lists in list comprehension:

```
import ast

L = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df["column"]]
print (L)
[['tablet', 'mobile', 'man'], ['people', 'house'], 
 ['people', 'computer'], ['computer', 'laptop']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `df` is like

```
                      column
0  ['tablet', 'mobile, man']
1        ['people', 'house']
2      ['people, 'computer']
3     ['computer', 'laptop']
```

You can get the list by calling the column with `tolist()`

```
df["column"].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['tablet', 'mobile', 'man'], ['people', 'house'], ['people', 'computer'], ['computer', 'laptop']]
```

Comment: No, the items of each column are in string format (like 'tablet') as I stated in my question. So, this solution won't help.

Comment: You said  lists of strings , like ['tablet', 'mobile', 'man'], Then this should work I guess. Did you tried that. Any error if its not working??

Comment: yes. I have tried.  It's giving me the output like: ["['tablet', 'mobile', 'man']", "['people', 'house']", "['people', 'computer']", "['computer', 'laptop']"]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

result_list = []

df = pd.read_csv("file_name")
series_1 = df.loc[::, "column_name"]

for s in series_1:
    list1 = s.strip("[]").replace(" ", "").replace("'", "").split(",")
    result_list.append(s)

print(result_list)
```

Comment: Since you've two answer (this one seems to be the one answering to the real question. While also being the faster answer so far), you may want to remove the wrong version.